# Apache 2.2.12, SSL and VirtualHost

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2

I used to have multiple VirtualHost listening and same ip and port with SSL enabled.
Of course only one certificate is used for every SSL connexion but this is OK for me.

I have a configuration that looks like http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

The problem is that since Apache 2.2.12 and SNI support this is no longer working. (I do not want to use SNI.)
Apache is not listening on port 443 if I use more than 1 SSL VirtualHost 
There is nothing in log, even with debug level.

Does anyone have a workaround ?